# How to properly receive the DOMContentLoaded event from an XUL iframe?

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon, dom-events, xul

I'm working on a minimal Firefox extension that loads a web page into an XUL iframe.  (I also tried the `html:iframe`, but met identical results.)  The page may take some time to load completely - and I'm trying to receive the `DOMContentLoaded` event, which should come before the `load` event.

(The main reason being that I'm trying to inject a CSS stylesheet, and this should be done immediately after the DOMContentLoaded event, instead of waiting and having the page appear "unstyled" until the load event.  However, this will be used for other reasons as well, so CSS-specific alternatives aren't a viable work-around.)

However, so far, I'm only able to receive the `load` event - and not the `DOMContentLoaded` nor the `readyState` events.

The issue should be easily reproducible using the below XUL, and simply entering the path to the XUL in the Firefox location bar given its `chrome://` URL (similar to [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Chrome_URLs)):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE window>
<window xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <script type="application/x-javascript">
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
            try{
                var outElem = document.getElementById("out");
                var out = function(s){
                    outElem.value += s + "\n";
                };

                var frameTest = document.getElementById("iframe-test");

                out("start: " + frameTest.contentDocument.readyState);
                frameTest.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
                    function(e){
                        out("DOMContentLoaded! " + e);
                    },
                    true);
                frameTest.addEventListener("readystatechange",
                    function(e){
                        out("readystatechange: " + e);
                    },
                    true);
                frameTest.addEventListener("load",
                    function(e){
                        out("load: " + e + ", state: " + frameTest.contentDocument.readyState);
                    },
                    true);
                out("all listeners registered, frame location: " + frameTest.contentWindow.location + ", state: " + frameTest.contentDocument.readyState);
            }catch(e){
                alert(e);
            }
        }, true);
    </script>

    <iframe id="iframe-test" type="content" src="http://www.google.com" height="400" width="400"/>
    <textbox id="out" rows="10" cols="80" multiline="true"/>

</window>
```

The output I'm receiving in the debug text box is:

```
start: uninitialized
all listeners registered, frame location: about:blank, state: uninitialized
load: [object Event], state: complete
```

I can't figure out why I don't receive any `DOMContentLoaded!` or `readystatechange:` outputs.

Another minimal example that also doesn't work is available at https://gist.github.com/2985342.

Pages I've already referenced include:

- [In XUL, how do I know a browser-tag has finished loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835313/in-xul-how-do-i-know-a-browser-tag-has-finished-loading)
- [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference

I've mentioned this on irc.mozilla.org/#extdev, and was only able to obtain a response of "Works for everyone else.", and "Best to use capturing listeners, though." - which is why I have the 3rd `useCapture` argument set to `true` in all the above `addEventListener` calls (though I haven't noticed any difference yet with setting this to false or omitting it entirely).

I'm looking to do this "the right way", without resorting to polling on `contentDocument.readyState`.

**Update:**  This and other similar examples work as expected when sampled through the "Real-time XUL Editor" (part of https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/extension-developer/), for example - but not when loaded as a `chrome://test/content/test.xul` file.  Is it true that when loaded through the location bar, that there are restricted privileges, etc., that are causing this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Gecko documentation, [DOMFrameContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMFrameContentLoaded) should work as an alternative event listener:

> The DOMFrameContentLoaded event is executed when a frame has finished loading and being parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to be done loading. This event is similar to DOMContentLoaded but only applies to frames.

Firefox and Opera(Mini or desktop 12 and under which use the Presto Engine) support this event:

> Currently, Firefox and Opera both implement DOMFrameContentLoaded events.
>
> When a frame has been loaded, Opera dispatches an event on the owner `iframe`. This event then bubbles up to the `window`.
>
> Firefox dispatches an event on the document on the owner `iframe`. It bubbles to the `window`. The target of that element is the `iframe` whose content has loaded. If the owner document is itself contained in a `frame`, an event is dispatched to the parent document. `event target` is still the frame when content has loaded (and so on to the top of the parent document chain).

**References**

- [Webkit Bug 33604 - iframe.contentWindow doesn't fire DOMContentLoaded (implement DOMFrameContentLoaded?)](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33604)

Answer (score 1):

Does the issue happen when you open your XUL page through the Firefox menu > Web Developer > Error Console > `open("chrome://yourpage.xul", "", "width=640,height=480");`? The browser that is beneath the location bar is marked as content-primary, which makes the pages in there run with restricted privileges, regardless of the protocol that the page is coming from (this is counter-intuitive, granted). It could be what's causing your issue, but I'd be unable to tell you the exact reason why, unfortunately.

The next step for such subtle issues involves connecting to irc.mozilla.org#developers and asking about your problem when the west coast is awake :).

Comment: No difference.  The window pops-up, but I see the identical 3 lines of debug output in each - no `DOMContentLoaded!` or `readyStateChange` outputs.  See my update above, though - it works in the "Real-time XUL Editor".  I see other things that are working that would only work with Chrome privileges, so I don't think this is the issue - but is something that should maybe be investigated further.

Comment: Correct, if your code doesn't work in a standalone window either, it's not due to the privilege restriction code I had in mind.